# How to send string value from one activity to other if string is public to be used in second activity?

Tags: android, string, android-intent

I am creating a book like app which has 3 buttons on opening.
I want to display different PDF files when user clicks on different buttons, each button opens certain PDF file present in assets folder.

**Button Onclicklistener, Intent**

```js
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hyp_funweb);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String easyPuzzle  = "fun.pdf";

            Intent i = new Intent (hyp_fun.this, Pdfviewer.class);

            i.putExtra("puzzle", easyPuzzle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**pdfviewer.java**

```js
package org.pavantech.studyinter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;

public class Pdfviewer extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;
    public String FILE =getIntent().getStringExtra("puzzle");
//here public String FILE =getIntent().getStringExtra("puzzle"); is my problem


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)

                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

anyone please help to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

    FILE = getIntent().getStringExtra("puzzle");
    displayFromAsset(FILE);
}
```

Move it to oncreate